# how to update table using api in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, insert-update

I'm stuck at updating table row using api in codeigniter,
i already have read tutorial from [code tutsplus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814)

but there's no spesific to do it,
so i tried by myself and got stuck :-(

url request:

```
http://localhost/work/bnilife/v1/signup/user/post?nopol=a1b2c3d4e5&username=agus&password=kucingtikus&captcha=c12ds
```

Here's the json respon:

```
{
"error": "error :-( "
}
```

My Controller look like this below:

```
public function user_post()
  {
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
    $datestring ="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s";
    $time       =time();
    $datetime   =mdate($datestring, $time);

    $data = array (
            'nopol'   => $this->input->get_post('nopol'),
            'username'   => $this->input->get_post('username'),
            'password'   => sha1($this->input->get_post('password')),
            'created_at' => $datetime,
            'updated_at' => $datetime
    );

    $result = $this->signup_m->signup_insert($data);
    if($result) {
      $this->response($data, 200);
    } else {
      $this->response(array('error' => 'error :-( '),400);
    }
  }
```

My model:

```
  public function signup_insert($data) {

  // Query to check whether username already exist or not
  $condition = "nopol=" . "'" . $data['nopol'] . "'" ;
  $this->db->where($condition);
  $this->db->update('user', $data); }
```

Is there any something wrong or misstype,
thank you guys
i'm new at this stuff.

Comment: 1). What you really want to do 2) You have written within your model `// Query to check whether username already exist or not` and instead of checking you are updating your fields directly 3) `if($result)` it doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check codeigniter documentation how are working Database methods http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database

```
public function signup_insert($data) {
  $this->db->where('nopol',$data['nopol']);
  return $this->db->update('user', $data); 
}
```

In your case you need and return else you can't use the method as $result as it will be equal to NULL..

- Check and CI Form Validation library as you don't validate your input data (even escaped) it may generate problems.
- And importantly, you should write proper method names: `signup_insert` should `INSERT` not `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

`'nopol'   => $this->input->get_post('nopol') in this change to 'nopol'   => $this->input->get_post('no_polis'),`

also  $this->db->where($condition) $condition is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Like @svetlio said,
i add some solution if **nopol** is typo(misstype) or null.
it will return false,
so i add some code to do it.
like this below:

```
if ($this->db->affected_rows() === 1) {
    return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
  }
```

so it wont be like:

```
return $this->db->update('user', $data);
```